# Take photos with "portrait" mode (bokeh) in iOS 11 / iPhone 7/8plus in 3rd-party app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11

The iPhone 7 plus and 8 plus (and X) have an effect in the native camera app called "Portrait mode", which simulates a bokeh-like effect by using depth data to blur the background.

I want to add the capability to take photos with this effect in my own app.

I can see that in iOS 11, depth data is available. But I have no idea how to use this to achieve the effect.

Am I missing something -- is it possible to turn on this effect somewhere and just get the image with it applied, rather than having to try and make this complicated algorithm myself?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately portrait mode and portrait lighting aren't open to developers as of iOS 11 so you would have to implement a similar effect on your own. [Capturing Depth in iPhone Photography](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/) and [Image Editing with Depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/508/) from this years WWDC go into detail on how to capture and edit images with depth data.

There are two sample projects on the developer site that show you how to capture and visualize depth data using a Metal shader, and on how to detect faces using AVFoundation. You could definitely use these to get you started! If you search for `AVCam` in the Guides and Sample Code they should be the first two that come up (I would post the links but stack overflow is only letting me add two).